# resizing a byte[] two's complement represented integer

Tags: java, arrays, byte, bit-manipulation, twos-complement

I have a two's complement representation of a number, in a byte array, and I want to expand it to use a larger byte array.
(You can get two's complement `byte[]` out of `BigInteger`s)

So my new byte array must have the same sign bit (ie highest bit)
and then everything else shifted.

so:

```
byte[] resize (byte[] raw, int len)
{
byte high = raw[0];

resized[0] = high & 0x80 //ie binary 1000 0000
raw[0] = high & 0x7F // 0111 1111
//causes a side effect but i don't care raw is a throw away value

byte[] resized = new byte[len];
    system.ArrayCopy(raw,0,resized,len-raw.length, len);
}
```

Am I on the right track?
I'm having trouble getting my head around, byte length hex literals work.
Or do my hex literals have to be int sized?
If so I'm going to have to cast my everything.

so is:

```
resized[0] = (byte) ((int)high & 0x8000)
raw[0] = (byte)((int)high & 0x7FFF)
```

The equivalent?

Comment: You might want to re-title your post, because "byte bashing" doesn't mean a lot to me.

Comment: Sure, Bytebashing (or more normally bit bashing) refers to modifying or interacting with values in the componany bytes (or more normally bits)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1: save the sign bit (i.e: the Most Significant bit)
Step 2: the new padding bits should be the same as the sign bit. Example:

```
1 byte: 11110001 
2 bytes: 1111111111110001
8 bytes: 1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111110001
```

for positive values is the same:

```
1 byte: 00001111
2 bytes: 0000000000001111
8 bytes: 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001111
```

Notice that when performing bitwise operations, the bytes are promoted to ints. Padding bytes will thus be 00h or FFh depending on the sign. The rest of the bytes are the same as the originals.

The sign can be determined as follows:

```
//If the MSB were raw[0]:
boolean isNegative = false;
if(raw[0] & 0x80 != 0){
      isNegative = true;
}
```

Comment: Your right about the sign bit being what ishould be usingfor padding,
But the problem I'm having is how do i recover the sign bit?

Comment: cool thanks. So you can express bytes as hex literals, cool.
My other option would be isNegitive == (raw[0]>>7 ==1) I guess

Comment: About the bytes as hex literals, I don't know what you exactly mean, but for instance `0x80` is an int.

Comment: I mean, can i get away with operating between raw[0] & 0x80?
If 0x80 is an int then is is of different type to raw[0]

Comment: And your operation swould be `(raw[0] >>> 7) == 1`, because the `>>` operator is the signed shift and maintains the sign bit. Well, actually, as raw[0] is first promoted to int and then shifted, you'd have to do `((raw[0] >>> 7) & 1) == 1`

Comment: Yes, every bitwise operation first converts all the operands to ints. With other operators, it is fine to mix bytes and shorts with ints, because these are all compatible.

Comment: they are compatable along the same lines of 0x80 maps to 0xFF80 since both are negitive.

Comment: I ended up basing my solution of this, but I think i though insome higher level things like checking the Sigb bitusingthe >/< signs.
Thanks